# Defining the concept of "library-safe" code

Tags: c++, c, language-agnostic, posix, libraries

First of all, I hope this question isn't too open-ended. As an ingredient for use in coding standards/policy, comparison of libraries/APIs, etc. I'm looking to establish a formal or at least semi-formal definition for the adjective "library-safe". In order not to be imposing my own view, or other arbitrary views, of best-practices as part of the definition, I want to avoid an overly restrictive definition. As an example of what I mean, deeming any code that accesses non-const-qualified objects of static storage duration, or alters other process-global state (e.g. signal dispositions), to be library-unsafe would probably be a working definition, but it's much stricter than it needs to be.

The essential properties I'm looking to capture, which I think are understood when one speaks of code as "library-safe", are:

1. Ability to have multiple "users" of the library code in the same process, whether that means multiple instances (recursion or threads) of the same code using the library code, or completely separate parts of the program using the library code, without these users stepping on each others' toes.
2. Not modifying state that "belongs to" the caller except as documented in the interface contract.

The kinds of answers I would consider good for this question would be references to similar past attempts at defining this concept, strong ideas for putting together the definition, or convincing arguments that attempting to define this concept precisely is futile.

By the way, I've tagged this C, C++, and POSIX because these are the contexts I'm most interested in applying such a definition in. It may be less interesting in the context of other languages; for instance, in a very pure functional language, all code should probably be considered "library-safe".

---

A proposed definition:

A library L is library-unsafe if there exist programs A and B such that:

- A and B take no input.
- A and B produce no output except exit status.
- A and B do not invoke undefined behavior.
- A and B do not contain any code outside of L that alters global state.
- Combining A and B into a single program, renaming functions or objects outside of L if necessary to avoid collisions, such that the main functions of A and B each run in their own thread, results in a program that invokes undefined behavior or whose outputs differ from the output of running A and B separately.

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree that your criteria of not accessing non-const qualified global state is probably excessively strict. In particular it may well be entirely reasonable for C code in a library to modify `errno` to let higher level code know why a failure occurred.

Many of the requirements (as I'd see them, anyway) probably apply more to documentation than the code itself. Modifying `errno` is fine, but *certainly* needs to be documented.

For C++ code, exception safety is somewhat similar. Obviously you want most code to provide the strongest exception safety it (reasonably) can, but the exact level provided is much less important than documentation of what it provides.

Comment: `errno` is not global state. It has thread storage duration, and as such it's possible to safely save and restore it, or (more likely) to treat it as a separate output temporary as if it were a secondary return value of functions that automatically propagates.

Answer (score 0):

[ACSL](http://frama-c.com/acsl_tutorial_index.html) is a specification language for C functions. It follows the Design-by-Contract philosophy. However, it is not intended to be compiled to run-time assertions, which is the most usual way pre- and post-conditions are put to use in other Design-by-Contract-inspired frameworks.

This may seem like an off-topic answer, because what you are asking, if I understand correctly, is for a common notion of what proper library functions do, whereas ACSL is for specifying what an individual function does. But I do think that the two must go together. The only definition of a “proper library function” is as “a function that does what it says”. Anything less generic would too restrictive. As an example, a proper library function should not de-allocate memory in general… unless it is `free()` or is specified as de-allocating memory.

---

So, at the very least, looking at what ACSL anticipates and what the defaults are for some of the ACSL clauses can suggest properties that a proper library function should have **unless otherwise specified**:

- an ACSL contract describe the function's expectations in a pre-condition, and the guarantees it offers in a post-condition.
- an ACSL contract implies that the function terminates for all inputs that satisfy the precondition, although it is possible to specify otherwise. Two ways for a function not to terminate are to loop forever or to cause the program to exit.
- memory locations passed to the function are allowed to alias unless specified otherwise in the pre-condition.
- an ACSL contract describes all memory locations the function may modify. Any memory location not listed cannot be modified by a call to the function.
- Optionally, it describes which memory locations are read for the computation of each output. Two calls to the function placed in memory states what differ only outside this list of read memory locations change the same memory locations and set them to the same values.
- memory blocks that are dynamically allocated or freed during the function call are listed in specific ACSL clauses. By default, a function neither allocates nor frees memory.

Some side-effects, such as changing the FPU rounding mode, are not modeled in ACSL but can be seen as changing global variables. Other side-effects (creating threads, installing signal handlers) refer to aspects of C that are outside ACSL's scope.

An example of ACSL contract:

```
/*@ requires \valid(((char*)s)+(0..n - 1));
  @ assigns ((char*)s)[0..n - 1] \from c;
  @ assigns \result \from s;
  @ ensures \forall integer i; (0 <= i < n) ==> ((char*)s)[i] == (char) c;
  @ ensures \result == s;
  @*/
void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);
```

---

As a last note on both the practical use of ACSL and the practical informal specification of libraries, the C language is such that there is a trade-off between encapsulation and specification. In particular, if a library function that modifies a `static` variable, this variable cannot be omitted from the specification, although it is out-of-scope for the caller.

A function such as `random()` does not assign `\result \from \nothing`, because that would imply that two successive calls always return the same result. On the other hand, a function such as `double sin(double x);` can be described by the clause `assigns \result \from x;` because two calls to `sin()` return the same result as soon as the argument is the same (FPU rounding mode notwithstanding. If the FPU rounding mode were modeled as a global variable, it would be an input of this function.)

Comment: "Does what it says it does" is too loose a definition; it doesn't guarantee that you have have multiple independent users of the library. The problematic situation I have in mind is where you have two libraries libA and libB which both use libC, and want to use both libA and libB (which were not written with awareness of each other's existence). If libC is not usable in multiple instances, your "does what it says it does" definition would mean that libA and libB need to document that they use libC and thus that they can't be used alongside other libraries that use libC.

Comment: But I would not call that "being library-safe". I would call that "documenting that they're not library-safe".

Comment: Also, your proposed definition may be too strong. To cite your example: "As an example, a proper library function should not de-allocate memory in general… unless it is free() or is specified as de-allocating memory." On the contrary, a function could be perfectly library-safe if it maintained an internal cache/memoization which it freed upon reaching a certain size threshold, as long as access is properly synchronized. I would not call this good design (personally, I consider almost any global state bad design), but I don't think it violates the principle of being library-safe.